# tfs 2010 database bug location

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at a sql server database for a tfs 2010 install and I am trying to find bugs/files logged by date.

Is this information contained in the database?

I see other information such as a view named WorkItemChanges which shows all the stories that have been changed by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** Directly querying the collection database is unsupported ***

The `Tfs{YourProjectCollection}` database contains all work items for a specific project collection. They live in the different Work Item tables, since a bug is a specific type of work item.

If your TFS environment is configured for reporting using Report Server, then you can use the Analysis cube or the TFSWarehouse databases to query this kind of information. For work items, a limited set of fields is stored and the same goes for files in source control. You should at least be able to find out which have changed. The following doc describes the warehouse structure: [Creating, Customizing and Managing reports for Visual Studio ALM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). A quick way to get started is from the Excel Powerpivot reports which are installed to your team project by default if your TFS instance is connected to a Sharepoint server with teh appropriate features enabled.

*** You have a number of alternatives ***

I suppose that your Visual Studio is currently working, if that's the case then there is no need to use a SQL query to get to the information you're after.

To query all bugs (or other work item types) that have changed between two dates, create a work item query (in Visual Studio) that looks like this:

[image: Work item query for bugs changed between two dates]

You can import these into Excel for easy manipulation or further aggregation. And you can even quickly create a Report from that. More information can be found in the [Bulk Add or Modify work items in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286627.aspx).

To query all files changed between a specific date range, is a little harder. You can quickly get all changesets between two dates using the commandline using `tf history $/Project /collection:yourprojectcollectionUri /recursive /version"D2012-10-10~D2013-10-10"` this will popup  window with all changesets between these dates. You can specify `/noprompt /format:detailed` to dump all details to the command prompt window.

Alternatively, you can do a folder diff between two dates. This [can be done from the UI in the Source Control Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385981%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Or from the commandline using `tf diff` or `tf folderdiff`